# Error com tag php no smarty

Tags: php, template

Estou com uma dúvida relacionada ao template engine smarty 3.1, estou tentando usar as tags {php}{/php} nos templates e estou recebendo o seguinte error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "file:/var/www/html/caf/view/index.tpl" on line 67 "{php}" {php}{/php} tags not allowed. Use SmartyBC to enable them <-- thrown in /var/www/html/caf/lib/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 67

Sei que se eu usar a classe SmartyBC no lugar da Smarty vai funcionar normalmente, mas vi que esse é um método deprecated na versão 3.1 e que a classe SmartyBC é uma classe de adaptação.

A minha dúvida é: Já que usar as tags {php}{/php} está deprecated, qual seria a forma correta de executar código php nos templates nessa nova versão?

Seria usando os register plugins https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl ?

Tentei usar os register plugins com o metodo getPage da minha classe rotas e não deu certo

classe

```
class Rotas {

    public static $pag;
    private static $dir_controller = 'controller';
    private static $dir_view = 'view';

    static function getPage() {
        if (isset($_GET['pag'])) {

            $pagina = $_GET['pag'];

            self::$pag = explode("/", $pagina);

            $pagina = 'controller/' . self::$pag[0] . '.php';

            if (file_exists($pagina)) {
                include $pagina;
            } else {
                include 'error.php';
            }
        }
    }

    static function getUrlBase() {
        return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . Config::APP_DIR;
    }

    static function getUrlHome() {
        return Config::APP_URL . '/' . Config::APP_DIR;
    }

    static function getTemplate() {
        return self::getUrlHome () . '/' . self::$dir_view;
    }

}
```

Estou tentando usar assim:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("function", "getPage", Rotas::getPage());
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o meu problema, caso alguém tenha essa dúvida futuramente a solução que encontrei no meu caso foi usar o método registerPlugin do smarty que de acordo com a documentação é o recomendado, e no meu caso descrito acima a solução ficou assim:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("function", "get_page", array("Rotas", "getPage"));
```

Para chamar o plugin no template é só usar o nome que você deu para ele, dentro de chaves:

```
{get_template}
```

Obs: o nome do plugin não pode ter o mesmo nome do seu método/função pois da error (demorei descobrir isso rsrsrs).

[Link da documentação do registerPlugin](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl)